# A method is ambiguous upon passing a lambda expression in Java

Tags: java, generics, exception, lambda, java-8

Let's have a functional interface `Functional` (for sake of brevity, I omitted the implementation and simplified the case):

```
@FunctionalInterface 
public interface Functional<E> { 

    void perform(E e);

    default <T extends Number> void method(E e, T t)  { }
    default <T extends Number> void method(E e, Function<E, T> function) { }
}
```

And a simple piece of code:

```
Functional<String> functional = (string) -> {};
functional.method("string", (string) -> 1);
```

Why is the method `method()` ambiguous since there is lambda passed as a parameter? This should be easily distinguished.

**Eclipse**:

> The method `method(String, Function<String,Integer>)` is ambiguous for the type `Functional<String>`

This is reproducible on **IntelliJIdea** as well.

**Javac output** (thanks to [@AndyTurner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner)):

```
Main.java:21: error: reference to method is ambiguous
        functional.method("string", (string) -> 1);
                  ^
  both method <T#1>method(E,T#1) in Functional and method <T#2>method(E,Function<E,T#2>) in Functional match
  where T#1,E,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Number declared in method <T#1>method(E,T#1)
    E extends Object declared in interface Functional
    T#2 extends Number declared in method <T#2>method(E,Function<E,T#2>)
```

and

```
Main.java:21: error: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        functional.method("string", (string) -> 1);
                         ^
    (argument mismatch; Number is not a functional interface)
  where T,E are type-variables:
    T extends Number declared in method <T>method(E,T)
    E extends Object declared in interface Functional
```

---

**Edit**: An interesting fact. When I replace `default <T extends Number>` with `<T>`, it works. The `T` seems cannot extend `Number`, `Throwable` etc...

```
default <T> void method(E e, T t)  { }
default <T> void method(E e, Function<E, T> function) { }
```

---

**Edit 2**: When I make the generic type `T` to the interface declaration, it works as well:

```
@FunctionalInterface 
public interface Functional<E, T extends Number> { 

    void get(E e);

    default void method(E e, Function<E, T> function) { }
    default void method(E e, T t)  { }
}
```

Comment: I would expect `<T extends Number>` to work and `<T>` to fail because it would be compatible with any argument. Interesting that the opposite is the case. For the record, it doesn't make a difference if the second method has `extends Number`.

Comment: @shmosel `Function` is strictly narrower than `Object`, but `Number` and `Function` are "tied."  (And there _could_ be a class that extends `Number` and implements `Function`.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Such a class could never be implemented/instantiated as a lambda.

Comment: It also seems to work when you reference the lambda from a variable `Function<String, ? extends Number>`. Seems strange that it can't properly infer which method to use when inlined.

Comment: Please tell which exact versions of jdk are you using

Comment: I've tested this with java 11 and it's not compiling either. It seems a bug to me. How could `(string) -> 1` be a `Number` ever?

Comment: Interestingly, providing the explicit type parameter makes the ambiguity disappear, i.e. `functional.<Number>method("string", (string) -> 1);` works fine.

Comment: there is a reason some languages do not allow overloading methods, every time you mix overload with poly expressions, like lambda expression, things tend to be "simple" from a developer's point - for the compiler things are a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple tickets ([here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173097), [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8057895) and [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170842)) that contain similar code snippets. These tickets are resolved as "Not an issue" and the explanation is as follows:

> [JLS 15.12.2.1:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.1)
>
> An expression is potentially compatible with a target type according
>   to the following rules:
>
> - [...]
> - A lambda expression or a method reference expression is potentially
>     compatible with a type variable if the type variable is a type
>     parameter of the candidate method.

So, both methods `method` are potentially compatible in this case.

Also, the lambda `(string) -> 1` is not pertinent to applicability, because:

> [JLS 15.2.2.2:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2)
>
> An argument expression is considered pertinent to applicability for a
>   potentially applicable method `m` unless it has one of the following
>   forms
>
> - [...]
> - If `m` is a generic method and the method invocation does not provide
>     explicit type arguments, an explicitly typed lambda expression or an
>     exact method reference expression for which the corresponding target
>     type (as derived from the signature of m) is a type parameter of `m`.

Finally:

> Since the `method` has a type-parameter where the lambda is
>   passed as argument, the lambda is skipped from the applicability check
>   - meaning both are applicable - hence the ambiguity.

Possible workaround - cast the argument when calling the method:

```
functional.method("string", (Function<String, Number>) (string) -> 1);
```